# Rotate a vignette over an image

Tags: css

My page: https://galina.xyz/makiyazh/oshibki-pri-makiyazhe/

HTML:

```html
<figure class="n-spin-container wp-block-image size-full">
  <img loading="lazy" width="390" height="500" src="https://galina.xyz/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/neve-food-mag-20.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-68">
</figure>
```

CSS:

```css
.n-spin-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: border-radius 1s ease-out;
  border-radius: 60% 40% 30% 70% / 60% 30% 70% 40%;  
}
```

[image]

I have failed to make this egg shape image frame to rotate slowly. The image itself is fixed. Only the vignette should be rotating. What can  try next?

Comment: `transition` specifies how to... well, transition, between two states. You still need to apply the new style for it to transition to. Alternatively, you might want to look into [keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)

Comment: If i try your code in a stack snippet there is no border-radius. Are you sure that it's working?

Comment: You are rotating the image along with the `figure` ..

Comment: @DeepakKamat He wrote: "*The image itself is fixed. Only the vignette should be rotating*"...

Comment: @biberman I go to the example url he put and there image is rotating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use @keyframe for making infinite rotating effect, because transition animate only between 2 states, example [here][1] without rotate but idea is there

```
  [1]: https://codepen.io/Zerhogi/pen/dyzojXw
```

```css
.n-spin-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  transition: border-radius 1s ease-out;
  border-radius: 60% 40% 30% 70% / 60% 30% 70% 40%;
  animation: rotate 5s linear infinite;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0%{
    border-radius: 60% 40% 30% 70% / 60% 30% 70% 40%;
  }
  20%{
    border-radius: 60% 30% 70% 40% / 60% 40% 70% 30%;
  }
  40%{
    border-radius: 70% 40% 80% 50% / 70% 50% 80% 40%;
  }
  60%{
    border-radius: 80% 50% 90% 60% / 80% 80% 90% 50%;
  }
  80%{
    border-radius: 90% 60% 100% 70% / 90% 70% 100% 60%;
  }
  100%{
    border-radius: 60% 40% 30% 70% / 60% 30% 70% 40%;
  }
}
```

```html
<figure class="n-spin-container wp-block-image size-full"><img loading="lazy" width="390" height="500" src="https://galina.xyz/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/neve-food-mag-20.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-68"></figure>
```

Comment: There's nothing on this pen, also can you share some code right here with an explanation why it will work?